# PHP based permission for Page Drupal

Tags: php, api, drupal, module

How can I set PHP condition for access argument in my own module?

If it returns true, then we have access to particular page. If false, we have not access to.

**Added:** I have variable for each user, true or false. So I need to restrict access to page(also menu should not be shown) if it is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find more details in [Menu example in examples project](https://drupal.org/project/examples). But the important part is the "access callback":

```
# in hook menu:
$items['beeroclock'] = array(
  'title' => 'Beer-o-clock!',
  'page callback' => '_menu_example_menu_page',
  'page arguments' => array(),
  'access callback' => "is_it_friday_yet",
 );

 #in your module, global scope
 function is_it_friday_yet() {
   $access = FALSE;
   if (date('w') == 5) {
     $access = TRUE;
   }
   return $access;       
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For D6 look at the following hooks:

- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_perm/6
- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--node.php/function/hook_access/6

You find a lot of example code in every module, that gives you specific permissions.

Comment: I don't find solution. One is for nodes. Which is not applicable. Another works with permission. I need something dynamic. I have updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can also put your own php code inside a singular page if you don't need something "special"
[look here](http://drupal.org/project/contextphp)

Comment: This is not applicable, because I need to hide menu also. This should be Drupal core solution. I have edited my question.

Comment: -1, because this is not the appropriate way, and very much discouraged.